# How to get multiple range queries to work in elasticsearch?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to use multiple `range` queries in `elasticsearch 2.4.5`,  but it doesn't seem to work when combined with each other.

I'm building an online store which must have the ability to search and filter products, and I'm using `elasticsearch` to add those functionalities. The store must be able to filter products by the following fields: `price`, `num_in_stock`, and `popularity`.

Here's how each field is store internally by `elasticsearch`:

- `popularity` = `float` (i.e. 0.0098736465783, which will be converted to percent to indicate how popular the product is)
- `price` = `float` (i.e. 5.890000000, which will be rounded and converted to proper price format)
- `num_in_stock` = `long` (i.e. 10)

Here's what I know for sure:

2. When I perform a *single* range query with any field individually (`price`, `popularity`, or `num_in_stock`), it works fine. For instance, when I filter by popularity -- let's say `0.05 (5%)` - `0.75 (75%)` -- it works fine.
3. However, when I **combine** multiple `range` queries the `popularity` range query does not work. However the `price` and `num_in_stock` ranges do work. In the sample query below, the range `price` and `num_in_stock` works fine, but the range `popularity` does not work!

Here's a sample query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": {
                    "range": {
                      "popularity": {
                        "gte": 0,
                        "lte": 0.02
                      },
                      "price": {
                        "gte": 0,
                        "lte": 10.25
                      },
                      "num_in_stock": {
                        "gte": 0,
                        "lte": 15
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1
}
```

Here's what I get for the **response**:

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "store",
        "_type": "modelresult",
        "_id": "product.360",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "Tide Laundry Detergent",
          "price": 5.15,
          "popularity" : 0.044386262065587822,
          "num_in_stock": 5
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I wanted to filter by `popularity` from `0` to `0.02`, but it gives me a results with `popularity` greater than that!

This is a big problem for me because the store must have the ability to filter by multiple ranges at the same time. What are some strategies to handle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct construction of range queries is something like

```
"bool" : {
  "must" : [
    {
      "range" : {
        "popularity" : ...
      }
    },
    {
      "range" : {
        "price" : ...
      }
    },
    {
      "range" : {
        "num_in_stock" : ...
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! But i'm wondering why this query syntax works while mine doesn't? They both look the same to me?

Comment: yours is under `filter`